# JAX-RS not returning KMZ file

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS Web Service that returns a KMZ file.

I am running into an issue returning hte .kmz file when this is deployed to a test glassfish server. Deploying this code to a local glassfish server I have no issues and it returns the kmz normally.

```
@GET
@Path("bar/v1")
@Produces("application/vnd.google-earth.kmz")
public Response getKmz() {

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget resource = client.target(URL);

    System.out.println(resource.getUri().toString());

    Response test = resource.request().get();
    System.out.println(test.toString());
    return test;
}
```

When deployed to the test server the test.toString() being printed so this code is being called. There is no other errors in the logs.

Looking at the transaction in Firefox HttpRequester
 the request is as follows:

```
GET http://foo/bar/v1
accept: application/vnd.google-earth.kmz

-- response --
0
```

Any ideas what could be causing the file not to be returned? I checked the glassfish settings both locally and on the test server and they were the same.

Comment: Is it happening only for the kmz file or for other file types too in the same target host?

Comment: It's only the kmz file, other similar services return csv, json, and other formats without issues.

Comment: You mention that the `test.toString()` call is being shown.  Does the value look to be the same in both environments?